# Why can't I launch Deepin Software Center (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: software-center

I installed DSC from a PPA but when I click on its icon nothing happens! I cant lunch it.

I've also tried from terminal with this command: `deepin-software-center` but it gives me this error:

```
<class 'Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension'>
INFO     Init ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/deepin-software-center", line 83, in <module>
start_main()
File "/usr/bin/deepin-software-center", line 63, in start_main
software_center.run()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/software_center.py", line 1132, in run
self.ready_show()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/software_center.py", line 878, in ready_show
self.init_ui()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/software_center.py", line 828, in init_ui
self.preference_dialog = DscPreferenceDialog()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/preference.py", line 676, in __init__
self.mirrors_box = MirrorsBox()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/preference.py", line 542, in __init__
self.main_box.pack_start(self.create_mirror_select_table(), True, True)
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/preference.py", line 597, in create_mirror_select_table
self.current_mirror_hostname = utils.get_current_mirror_hostname()
File "/usr/share/deepin-software-center/ui/utils.py", line 106, in get_current_mirror_hostname
hostname = url.split(":")[0] + "://" + url.split("/")[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `sudo deepin-software-center`? Sometimes applications have odd ways to tell you that it needs root permissions to run right.

Comment: yes i did.but nothing happens!